# What are the constraints of FUN in H2O's apply function?

Tags: r, apply, h2o

I am using [h2o](/questions/tagged/h2o) version `3.10.4.8`.

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init(nthreads = -1)

df <- as.h2o(data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 11:15))
```

I'm trying to understand how to use the `apply()` function in `H2O`.

The following works as expected:

```
h2o::apply(df, 2, mean)
h2o::apply(df, 2, sum)
h2o::apply(df, 2, function(x) {2*x + 1})
```

But this does not:

```
h2o::apply(df, 2, sd)
```

The error returned is:

> [1] "Lookup failed to find is.H2OFrame" Error in .process.stmnt(stmnt,
>   formalz, envs) :    Don't know what to do with statement: is.H2OFrame
>   x

I also thought that `H2O` is actually using its own functions to do the computation, so the following should work:

```
h2o::apply(df, 2, h2o.mean)
h2o::apply(df, 2, h2o.sum)
h2o::apply(df, 2, h2o.sd)
```

But it does not. The first two lines give the following error:

> [1] "Lookup failed to find .newExpr" Error in .process.stmnt(stmnt,
>   formalz, envs) :    Don't know what to do with statement: .newExpr sd
>   x na.rm

While the third line gives the following error:

> [1] "Lookup failed to find .newExpr" Error in .process.stmnt(stmnt,
>   formalz, envs) :    Don't know what to do with statement: .newExpr sd
>   x na.rm

What's going on and what are the things I should be aware of when passing stuff into `FUN` parameter in the `apply()` function? The documentation simply describes `FUN` as "the function to be applied".

Comment: Still an **h2o** newbie, and hence not quite certain what's going on behind the curtains, but `h2o::apply(df, 2, function(x) { sd(x, na.rm = TRUE) })` solves your first issue.